# Product to sum formulas

Tags: trigonometry

Write the product as a sum.
cos 4x cos 2x

this is what i tried 
2{cos2xcosx} = 2[1/2 cos(2x+1x)+ cos(2-1)]
             = 1[cos(3x)+cos(1x)]
             = cos 3x + cos x

Comment: What is the problem? Also use [$\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write math.

Answer (score 0):

There is an identity:

$$\cos\alpha \cdot \cos\beta = \frac{\cos(\alpha-\beta) + \cos(\alpha+\beta)}{2}$$

You can find other useful formulas [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).

Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\cos (4x + 2x) = \cos 4x \cos 2x - \sin 4x \sin 2x
\\
\cos(4x-2x) = \cos 4x \cos 2x + \sin 4x \sin 2x
$$

Now make the half sum of these two, and you will get your result. Welcome!